# Google Cloud SDK Install Fail with Error 307 Temporarily Moved

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

[image: download failed]

This is on Windows 7 and I am not sure where it means that the connection is blocked by the corporate firewall or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the network you are connected uses a firewall, it may block the secure connection with google servers, sometimes, antivirus can cause this kind of issues too, try from a different network or disable antivirus if you have, also check that you have python 2.7.x as it is required by the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install).

Also, you can check the installer log at C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\DATE and check for details on the error.

Alternatively, you can try using one of the [previous available](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives).